# Find Contacts who are in one and only one group?

Tags: search, groups

i could write a sql query but is there a way to do this search from the UI?

Answer (score 2):

Since sql is probably your best bet, the sql is pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT c.display_name, 
       g.name, 
       count(*)
FROM   civicrm_group_contact gc,
       civicrm_contact c,
       civicrm_group g
where  gc.contact_id = c.id
and    gc.group_id = g.id
and    gc.status = 'Added'
group by 1
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to count the number of groups each contact is in (and select only those with a single group) then to SQL you shall go!

Comment: yes, but your solution makes the assumption that all contacts belong to one or more groups

Comment: I edited my answer down following Lobo's comment.  Its not reasonable (although it might actually be possible) to use the Custom Search Include/Exclude to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to model this as a custom search (i.e. embed your sql query in a custom search). Not sure if your description includes smart groups, in which case the problem is a bit more complicated.